# How to Create Azure Resource Graph Explorer Scheduled Reports and Email Alerts

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, kql

I have a Kusto query taken from [this example](https://www.blueboxes.co.uk/how-to-create-azure-resource-graph-explorer-scheduled-reports-and-email-alerts) that looks like this:

```
Resources 
| where type =~ 'microsoft.compute/virtualmachines' 
| extend vmPowerState = tostring(properties.extended.instanceView.powerState.code) 
| summarize count() by vmPowerState
```

I would like to create an weekly alert that send the result through an e-mail in a CSV file.

The Logic App is organized in 5 steps:

[image]

> One:

[image]

> Two:

With

- URL: https://management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.ResourceGraph/resources
- Body:

```
{
  "query": "Resources | where type =~ 'microsoft.compute/virtualmachines' | extend vmPowerState = tostring(properties.extended.instanceView.powerState.code) | summarize count() by vmPowerState"
}
```

[image]

> Three:

Where I parse the `Body`  and I give an extract of the JSON Schema:

```
{
    "count": 3,
    "data": [
        {
            "count_": 3,
            "vmPowerState": "PowerState/stopped"
        },
        {
            "count_": 29,
            "vmPowerState": "PowerState/deallocated"
        },
        {
            "count_": 118,
            "vmPowerState": "PowerState/running"
        }
    ],
    "skip_token": null,
    "total_records": 3
}
```

Here I have a few doubt because I found [a guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69583663/azure-logic-app-create-array-with-only-one-object) that says that I should use `array` formula instead. I'm not very sure about that because I cannot see the details in the example. Anyway this is what I do:

[image]

> Four:

[image]

> Five:

Where I create the attachment from the CSV

[image]

The e-mail in the end arrives but the attachment is not a CSV, it's a JSON file:

[image]

What the hack am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to use "Create CSV table" with Columns set to "Automatic", do pass the "body" of "parse Json".
[image]

you don't need to use the array variable but whatever you use need to return an array like this:

[image]

The body of the json parser on your example has many other json nodes enveloping that. You should have the option "data" as there is an array there called "data"

if you want to cut it short, try "data"

[image]

you can change to "custom". that would allow you to remove redundant data or format data (like the "PowerState" in "PowerState/stopped"):
[image]

you can also add the .csv to the file name:
[image]

The above worked for me but it can be enhanced

[image]

Comment: Hi @BrunoLucasAzure, I entered the JSON as you said but I only can see `body`: https://snipboard.io/GZlgBe.jpg . There are no `data` or `total_records`. Where should I find them?

Comment: Hi, I was able to incapsulate the JSON into the CSV like this: https://snipboard.io/SM8sri.jpg . The problem was that I was pasting the JSON straight into the "Parse JSON" without pasting it into the "Use sample payload to generate schema". The problem I have now is that with a simple Kusto query I receive the CSV but with a long Kusto query the data are not loaded. Maybe because the Kusto query takes more time? Have you ever incurred in something like this?

Comment: And that's why... the dammit Kusto query, when fired from an HTTP call has a next page token: https://snipboard.io/Eir3sg.jpg . It returns only 100 items but there are 610 in total so I need to skip other 6 pages. Any idea?

Comment: Ha,ha: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/integrations-on-azure-blog/logic-app-http-pagination-deeper-look-build-custom-paging/ba-p/2907605

Comment: Hi @Franceso Mantovani; sorry couldn't respond earlier. but look like you have figured out.

Answer (score 0):

The suggestoin posted by @BrunoLucasAzure really helped me understand how Logic Apps works.

However I would like to reply to my own question with the right solution: I had to paste a sample of the JSON output pressing on the button *Use sample payload to generate schema*.

[image]

Then follow the workflow and everything will be fine.

The next problem I need to fix is pagination but apparently there is a solution for that too: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/integrations-on-azure-blog/logic-app-http-pagination-deeper-look-build-custom-paging/ba-p/2907605