# Logic Apps :: parse JSON or CSV and make a list of e-mails separated by semi column

Tags: json, azure, csv, azure-logic-apps, azure-logic-app-standard

I created a [Logic Apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74657747/how-to-create-azure-resource-graph-explorer-scheduled-reports-and-email-alerts) that allows me to query the Azure Resource Graph Explorer and send a list of untagged resources through e-mail.

The Logic Apps is parsing JSON and putting the results in CSV. The CSV looks like this:

| name | type | location | tags_createdBy |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Resource | microsoft.compute/virtualmachines | westeurope | albert.einstein@contoso.com |
| Resource | microsoft.compute/virtualmachines | eastus | albert.einstein@contoso.com |
| Resource | microsoft.compute/virtualmachines | eastus | albert.einstein@contoso.com |
| Resource | microsoft.compute/virtualmachines | eastus | albert.einstein@contoso.com |
| Resource | microsoft.compute/virtualmachines | eastus | albert.einstein@contoso.com |
| Resource | microsoft.compute/virtualmachines | westeurope | albert.einstein@contoso.com |
| Resource | microsoft.compute/virtualmachines | eastus | albert.einstein@contoso.com |
| Resource | microsoft.compute/virtualmachines | eastus | albert.einstein@contoso.com |
| Resource | microsoft.compute/virtualmachines | eastus | albert.einstein@contoso.com |
| Resource | microsoft.compute/virtualmachines | germanywestcentral | albert.einstein@contoso.com |
| Resource | microsoft.compute/virtualmachines | westeurope | albert.einstein@contoso.com |
| Resource | microsoft.compute/virtualmachines | switzerlandnorth | albert.einstein@contoso.com |
| Resource | microsoft.sql/servers/databases | eastus |  |
| Resource | microsoft.storage/storageaccounts | westeurope |  |
| Resource | microsoft.storage/storageaccounts | switzerlandnorth | robert.fish@contoso.com |
| Resource | microsoft.storage/storageaccounts | eastus | robert.fish@contoso.com |
| Resource | microsoft.storage/storageaccounts | germanywestcentral | robert.fish@contoso.com |
| Resource | microsoft.storage/storageaccounts | germanywestcentral | robert.fish@contoso.com |
| Resource | microsoft.storage/storageaccounts | eastus |  |
| Resource | microsoft.storage/storageaccounts | eastus |  |
| Resource | microsoft.storage/storageaccounts | eastus | hello.world@contoso.com |
| Resource | microsoft.storage/storageaccounts | eastus |  |
| Resource | microsoft.storage/storageaccounts | westeurope |  |

I would like to parse the **tags_createdBy** column and take a list of e-mails.

In this case in example the e-mails will be only 3:

- albert.einstein@contoso.com
- robert.fish@contoso.com
- hello.world@contoso.com

I then would like to insert those e-mails in the list of recipients because I want them to receive that e-mail, like this:

[image]

So the question is how to:

1. parse JSON or CSV file
2. take each value only one and erase NULLs
3. separate each value by a column or semi column
4. insert that into the e-mail recipient in Logic App.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reproducing from my end, I could able to get this work by Parsing the json initially. Considering below is the Json, I have used Parse JSON action in order to extract `tags_createdBy` column.

```
[
  {
    "location": "westeurope",
    "name": "Resource",
    "tags_createdBy": "albert.einstein@contoso.com",
    "type": "microsoft.compute/virtualmachines"
  },
  {
    "location": "eastus",
    "name": "Resource",
    "tags_createdBy": "albert.einstein@contoso.com",
    "type": "microsoft.compute/virtualmachines"
  },
  {
    "location": "eastus",
    "name": "Resource",
    "tags_createdBy": "albert.einstein@contoso.com",
    "type": "microsoft.compute/virtualmachines"
  },
  {
    "location": "eastus",
    "name": "Resource",
    "tags_createdBy": "albert.einstein@contoso.com",
    "type": "microsoft.compute/virtualmachines"
  },
  {
    "location": "eastus",
    "name": "Resource",
    "tags_createdBy": "albert.einstein@contoso.com",
    "type": "microsoft.compute/virtualmachines"
  },
  {
    "location": "westeurope",
    "name": "Resource",
    "tags_createdBy": "albert.einstein@contoso.com",
    "type": "microsoft.compute/virtualmachines"
  },
  {
    "location": "eastus",
    "name": "Resource",
    "tags_createdBy": "albert.einstein@contoso.com",
    "type": "microsoft.compute/virtualmachines"
  },
  {
    "location": "eastus",
    "name": "Resource",
    "tags_createdBy": "albert.einstein@contoso.com",
    "type": "microsoft.compute/virtualmachines"
  },
  {
    "location": "eastus",
    "name": "Resource",
    "tags_createdBy": "albert.einstein@contoso.com",
    "type": "microsoft.compute/virtualmachines"
  },
  {
    "location": "germanywestcentral",
    "name": "Resource",
    "tags_createdBy": "albert.einstein@contoso.com",
    "type": "microsoft.compute/virtualmachines"
  },
  {
    "location": "westeurope",
    "name": "Resource",
    "tags_createdBy": "albert.einstein@contoso.com",
    "type": "microsoft.compute/virtualmachines"
  },
  {
    "location": "switzerlandnorth",
    "name": "Resource",
    "tags_createdBy": "albert.einstein@contoso.com",
    "type": "microsoft.compute/virtualmachines"
  },
  {
    "location": "eastus",
    "name": "Resource",
    "tags_createdBy": "",
    "type": "microsoft.sql/servers/databases"
  },
  {
    "location": "westeurope",
    "name": "Resource",
    "tags_createdBy": "",
    "type": "microsoft.storage/storageaccounts"
  },
  {
    "location": "switzerlandnorth",
    "name": "Resource",
    "tags_createdBy": "robert.fish@contoso.com",
    "type": "microsoft.storage/storageaccounts"
  },
  {
    "location": "eastus",
    "name": "Resource",
    "tags_createdBy": "robert.fish@contoso.com",
    "type": "microsoft.storage/storageaccounts"
  },
  {
    "location": "germanywestcentral",
    "name": "Resource",
    "tags_createdBy": "robert.fish@contoso.com",
    "type": "microsoft.storage/storageaccounts"
  },
  {
    "location": "germanywestcentral",
    "name": "Resource",
    "tags_createdBy": "robert.fish@contoso.com",
    "type": "microsoft.storage/storageaccounts"
  },
  {
    "location": "eastus",
    "name": "Resource",
    "tags_createdBy": "",
    "type": "microsoft.storage/storageaccounts"
  },
  {
    "location": "eastus",
    "name": "Resource",
    "tags_createdBy": "",
    "type": "microsoft.storage/storageaccounts"
  },
  {
    "location": "eastus",
    "name": "Resource",
    "tags_createdBy": "hello.world@contoso.com",
    "type": "microsoft.storage/storageaccounts"
  },
  {
    "location": "eastus",
    "name": "Resource",
    "tags_createdBy": "",
    "type": "microsoft.storage/storageaccounts"
  },
  {
    "location": "westeurope",
    "name": "Resource",
    "tags_createdBy": "",
    "type": "microsoft.storage/storageaccounts"
  }
]
```

Here is the flow of my logic app which extracts `tags_createdBy` from the json and saves it in an array variable using `Append to array variable`.

[image]

To remove duplicates and get only the unique values, I have used `union` and filtered the array to remove `null` values from the resultant. Below is the expression and the flow used in my logic app.

```
union(variables('tags_createdBy'),variables('tags_createdBy'))
```

Expression to replace ',' with ';'

```
replace(string(body('Filter_array')),',',';')
```

[image]

*RESULTS:*

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you, how have you added the `empty{...}` in the Filter Array?

Comment: There was a discrepancy between your code which has `"tags_createdBy": "",` and my code which has `"tags_createdBy": null,` but I fixed that. Thank you